# Am I breaking const-correctness if I expose a const and non-const API?

Tags: c++, constants, const-correctness

I'm designing a class and had some concerns about const-correctness, but I don't think I have a complete understanding of what the notion truly means. If I store a raw pointer to a non-const type and want to provide const and non-const accessors to that pointer, will that break const-correctness?

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    void SetCount(int* pCount)
    {
        m_pCount = pCount;
    }

    void GetCount(const int** ppCount) const
    {
        *ppCount = m_pCount;
    }

    void GetCount(int** ppCount) const
    {
        *ppCount = m_pCount;
    }

private:
    int* m_pCount = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    int count = 10;

    A a;
    a.SetCount(&count);

    const int* pCountConst = nullptr;
    a.GetCount(&pCountConst);

    // Prints 10.
    std::cout << *pCountConst << std::endl;

    int* pCountNonConst = nullptr;
    a.GetCount(&pCountNonConst);
    (*pCountNonConst)++;

    // Prints 11.
    std::cout << *pCountConst << std::endl;
}
```

`pCount`'s type is `const int*`, so we expect that the underlying `int` will never change once initialized. It seems to me that we're breaking const-correctness here, is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your semantics, but I don't think I would use the functions you have here. Instead, here are the two options I would consider:

If you want A to *own* this count variable, then you should probably preserve `const`-ness when accessing it. In this case, you might write your functions like this:

```
void GetCount(const int** ppCount) const
{
    *ppCount = m_pCount;
}

void GetCount(int** ppCount) // note - omitted const
{
    *ppCount = m_pCount;
}
```

This means that if you have a non-`const` `A` you can get a non-const counter, but if you have a `const` `A` you can only get a `const` counter.

---

You could also mean that A simply observes some count variable. In that context, a `const` observer means that you're not going to change which int you're pointing to, but that thing itself might change. In that case, you might write your accessor like this:

```
void GetCount(int** ppCount) const
{
    *ppCount = m_pCount;
}
```

---

In general I would say to prefer the first method and preserve `const`-ness, but the other way is certainly valid in certain circumstances.